# find string mathematical operator

Tags: python

I need help. I want to verified if a character who is stored in a list, exist in a string;

My list:

```
obj = ['<','>','=','<=']
```

My string

```
x ='a<=b'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `for` loop to iterate items from the list `obj`.
2. Use `if i in x` to check if item from the list `obj` is present in the string `x` or not.
3. According to status of step 2 add key values in the `result` dictionary.
4. Print result dictionary.

e.g.

```
>>> obj = ['<','>','=','<=']
>>> x ='a<=b'
>>> result = {} 
>>> for i in obj:
...     if i in x:
...        result[i]="Present in string."
...     else:
...        result[i]="Not in string"
... 
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'<': 'Present in string.',
 '<=': 'Present in string.',
 '=': 'Present in string.',
 '>': 'Not in string'}
>>>
```

---

More on `in` and `__contains__()` method of string:-

```
>>> "a" in "abcde"
True
>>> "z" in "abcde"
False
>>> "abcde".__contains__("a")
True
>>> "abcde".__contains__("z")
False
```

Comment: Everything makes sense now, this question *totally* deserves to be answered! Sorry for the downvote, please receive my sincere apologies in the form of upvote.

Comment: The sarcasm is strong with this one.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `<=` is different than `<` which is different than `<<<`. Because of this, you need to separate the multiple characters that comprise the operator from non-operator characters surrounding it.

In most cases, you would use a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) to do that.

In a simple case, the best way is with a regex:

```
tests='''\
a<=b
a<b
a>b
a<<<b
a=b
a==b
a>=b'''

import re

ops=['<','>','=','<=']

pat='([{}]+)'.format(''.join({c for op in ops for c in op}))
for test in tests.splitlines():
    m=re.search(pat, test)
    if m:
        print 'Line: "{}", Operator: "{}", in ops: {}'.format(
                            test, m.group(0), m.group(0) in ops)
```

Which prints:

```
Line: "a<=b", Operator "<=", in ops: True
Line: "a<b", Operator "<", in ops: True
Line: "a>b", Operator ">", in ops: True
Line: "a<<<b", Operator "<<<", in ops: False
Line: "a=b", Operator "=", in ops: True
Line: "a==b", Operator "==", in ops: False
Line: "a>=b", Operator ">=", in ops: False
```

If you do not care about `<` being distinct from `<=` you can just test each character of the string against the list with `any`:

```
>>> any(op in 'a<=b' for op in ['<','>','=','<='])
True
```

But that does not distinguish between `<` and `<=` which are different operators.